# Fingerprint Login option does not show in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader, 20.10

I have just updated to Ubuntu 20.10. I was interested in the fingerprint login option. I am using HP Probook 450 g2 laptop which does include a fingerprint scanner. I tried to enable the option and add fingerprints according to the instructions from [this page on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en). But in the user section from the settings, I do not see any option to add a fingerprint.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with an acer swift 3. Any tips on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on HP envy 13-aq1013dx and do not know how to fix it, I suppose that there are no drivers installed for the fingerprint reader I have on my PC. It would be great if anybody could help!